# Redirect htaccess part of url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to create a sort of wildcard to redirect to a new url.

I replaced a specific part, that should be redirected.

All url's that contain the following `/computers/notebooks-laptops/`

Should be redirect to `/computers/laptops/`

So the following URL

```
https://www.example.com/computers/notebooks-laptops/product1
```

should become:

```
https://www.example.com/computers/laptops/product1
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the `.htaccess` in root directory, use below rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/computers/notebooks-laptops/(.*)
RewriteRule ^ /computers/laptops/%1 [R=301,L]
```